# How to save Telerik RadBinaryImage image to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, telerik, insert-image

I have a Telerik RadBinaryImage control which is displaying an image loaded using Telerik RadAsyncUpload.

I have an SQL table containing a 'Photo' column (image data type). I want to save to the database the image from the Telerik RadBinaryImage to the insert function which look like this:

```
Private Sub InsertPhotoIntoDB()
        Dim sMyConn As String = My.Settings.appDBConnString
        Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
        myConnection = New SqlConnection(sMyConn)

        myConnection.Open()

        myCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Photos(Photo) VALUES(@Photo)")
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection

        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image, 0, "Photo")
        myCommand.Parameters("@Photo").Value = WhatDoIPutHere???

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        myConnection.Close()
        myConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I've tried:
`myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = RadBinaryImage1.DataValue`
 but I still get an error:

The parameterized query '(@Photo image)INSERT INTO Photos (Photo) VALUES (@Photo)' expects parameter '@Photo', which was not supplied.

Do I need to convert RadBinaryImage1.DataValue to image?

Answer (score 1):

The `RadBinaryImage` control is used to display an image coming from the database.  So, the sequence should be like this:

1. User uploads photo via `RadUpload`
2. Image stored in database using modified code (see below)
3. On PostBack, the page displays the image from the database using the `RadBinaryImage`

If you don't want to store in the database right away, you will need to persist the data yourself in some way (Could store the file on the filesystem and then access the path via `RadBinaryImage.SavedImageName`, or persist in memory as `Session["UploadedImage"]`).  The bottom line is RadBinaryImage is only meant to display an image on the page.

With regards to your sample code, I recommend using the SQL column type `varbinary` instead of `image`.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
         Handles Button1.Click
        For Each file As UploadedFile In RadUpload1.UploadedFiles
            Dim bytes(file.ContentLength - 1) As Byte
            file.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, file.ContentLength)
            Dim connection As OleDbConnection = CreateConnection()
            Try
                Dim command As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Images ([Name], [Size], [Content]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", connection)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", file.GetName())
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", bytes.Length)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", bytes)
                connection.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Finally
                If connection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                    connection.Close()
                End If
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
```

See this post for sample code and more explanation:
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-manipulating-files.html

Comment: Thank you, msigman. I think the error (The parameterized query .. was not supplied) occurs because RadBinaryImage doesn't persists the data, so there is nothing to save in the database. How can I persist the data in a temporary file, after I upload it and display it in a RadBinaryImage control?

Comment: That is the approach I described in my answer.  You need to persist to database first, and then display to RadBinaryImage after, on the PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to upload the image as a byte array:

```
Byte[] yourByteArray; 
...
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", yourByteArray);
```

How to get to a byte array differs.  With the ASP.NET Upload control, it's just:

```
yourByteArray = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

Or if the image is represented as a stream:

```
var yourByteArray = new Byte[ImageObject.InputStream.Length];
ImageObject.InputStream.Read(yourByteArray, 0, yourByteArray.Length);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I apply this to Telerik RadBinaryImage?

Comment: Try to set `yourByteArray` to the Telerik control's `DataValue` property?